# What is required to use background layer as specified in Tikz manual?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The example in [PGF/Tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) on the pp. 77-82 throws an error when incorporated into my simple org chart: `! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' could not be found. Maybe you misspelled it?.See the pgf package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}`

Realizing that example was not self-contained I did search for `background` but could not see it being explicitly declared, maybe I am missing something.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thin]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[anchor=south](Supervisor){Supervisor}[]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node {Teammate1}}
    child{node {Teammate2}}
    child{node {Teammate3}}
    child{node {Teammate4}}
    child{node {Teammate5}};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \clip[xshift=-1cm] (-.5\textwidth,-.5\textheight) rectangle ++(\textwidth,\textheight);
        \colorlet{upperleft}{green!50!black!25}
        \colorlet{upperright}{orange!25}
        \colorlet{lowerleft}{red!25}
        \colorlet{lowerright}{blue!25}
        % The large rectangles:
        \fill [upperleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,20);
        \fill [upperright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,20);
        \fill [lowerleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,-20);
        \fill [lowerright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,-20);
        % The shadings:
        \shade [left color=upperleft,right color=upperright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,20);
        \shade [left color=lowerleft,right color=lowerright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,-20);
        \shade [top color=upperleft,bottom color=lowerleft]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,2);
        \shade [top color=upperright,bottom color=lowerright]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,2);
    \end{pgfonlayer}         
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if that isn't explained in the user guide right where you found the example.

Comment: Same thought. Could you point me at the explanation? I thought it should have been in `6.5 Adding the Background` on p. 77 but cannot see it explained.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to first declare layers:

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzset{every node/.append style = {draw=black,thin}}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}   %% some additional layers for demo

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[ level 1/.style={sibling distance=6em}]
    \node[anchor=south](Supervisor){Supervisor}[]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node {Teammate1}}
    child{node {Teammate2}}
    child{node {Teammate3}}
    child{node {Teammate4}}
    child{node {Teammate5}};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \clip[xshift=-1cm] (-.5\textwidth,-.5\textheight) rectangle ++(\textwidth,\textheight);
        \colorlet{upperleft}{green!50!black!25}
        \colorlet{upperright}{orange!25}
        \colorlet{lowerleft}{red!25}
        \colorlet{lowerright}{blue!25}
        % The large rectangles:
        \fill [upperleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,20);
        \fill [upperright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,20);
        \fill [lowerleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,-20);
        \fill [lowerright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,-20);
        % The shadings:
        \shade [left color=upperleft,right color=upperright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,20);
        \shade [left color=lowerleft,right color=lowerright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,-20);
        \shade [top color=upperleft,bottom color=lowerleft]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,2);
        \shade [top color=upperright,bottom color=lowerright]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,2);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In version 3 of pgfmanual, this is explained in section 109.1,2 and 3 (109 Layered Graphics), on page 1084.  For version 2.1, see page 662, section 82.

Comment: The manual I downloaded from CTAN goes only to p.726. Where can I obtain the manual you referred to?

Comment: @ajeh At present, I don't have version 2 manual. Version 3 isn't officially released to tex distributions. You have to install it yourself: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/

Comment: @ajeh OK I have one for v2.1. See page 662 Section 82.

Comment: Link to manual v.2.1 is in the 1st line of the question, if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `backgrounds` library (section 43, pages 509-512 in pgfmanual v 3.0.0). It declares `main` and `background` layers and you don't need to use `\pgfdeclarelayer` commands. Instead of `pgfonlayer` environment, just add option `[on background layer]` to an `scope` environment.

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
...
\end{scope}
```

This syntax can be shortened with `scopes` library (section 12.3.2 Shorthand fo Scope Environments) which allows to write

```
{[on background layer]
...
}
```

Harish's code adapted to these commands looks like

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,scopes}   %<------- Load libraries
\tikzset{every node/.append style = {draw=black,thin}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[ level 1/.style={sibling distance=6em}]
    \node[anchor=south](Supervisor){Supervisor}[]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node {Teammate1}}
    child{node {Teammate2}}
    child{node {Teammate3}}
    child{node {Teammate4}}
    child{node {Teammate5}};

    {[on background layer] %<- Everything is drawn on background layer
        \clip[xshift=-1cm] (-.5\textwidth,-.5\textheight) rectangle ++(\textwidth,\textheight);
        \colorlet{upperleft}{green!50!black!25}
        \colorlet{upperright}{orange!25}
        \colorlet{lowerleft}{red!25}
        \colorlet{lowerright}{blue!25}
        % The large rectangles:
        \fill [upperleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,20);
        \fill [upperright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,20);
        \fill [lowerleft] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,-20);
        \fill [lowerright] (Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,-20);
        % The shadings:
        \shade [left color=upperleft,right color=upperright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,20);
        \shade [left color=lowerleft,right color=lowerright]([xshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(2,-20);
        \shade [top color=upperleft,bottom color=lowerleft]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(-20,2);
        \shade [top color=upperright,bottom color=lowerright]([yshift=-1cm]Supervisor) rectangle ++(20,2);
    } %<----- End background scope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see you get same results:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for asking this without MWE since it will be quite difficult at the moment. If I have a minimal document with only a TikZ pic, and it works fine. However, after trying to include all the tikz code inside my main document I get an error `Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' is not part of the' is part of this list. \scoped[on background layer]`. What might be wrong despite loading all the tikz libraries in my main document?

Comment: @Diaa You need to load `tikz` but also used tikzlibraries. In this case you have to include `\usetikzlibrary{scopes, backgrounds}` in your preamble.