# Filling a Fit Node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, fit

I'm trying to draw the following diagram using Tikz:
[image: Complexity Diagram]

I wrote the following to recreate a similar version of it

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{set/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,align=center}}
        \node[set,fill=blue!20,text width=3cm](P) at (0, -1) {P Problems};
        \node[set,fill=green!20,text width=3cm](NP) at (3,+1) {NP Complete};
        \node[fill=purple!20, fit=(P)(NP),draw,rounded corners=0.5cm,inner sep=1cm,label={NP Problems}]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But, of course, when I create the fit node, with the fill option, it  covers the fitted nodes over, yielding something like this:
[image: result]

How can I make the filling stay "behind" the other nodes, so as to not overwrite the fitted nodes (`P`, and `NP`)?

Comment: May be this question is not a duplicate of [`What is required to use background layer as specified in Tikz manual?`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159139/what-is-required-to-use-background-layer-as-specified-in-tikz-manual/159148#159148) but it has received similar answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PGF allows you to create and switch layers. For example this command:

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
```

will create a layer named `background`.

Then, you can configure the order of these layers with:

```
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
```

The `main` layer is, you guessed right, the main layer :P

This will set the `main` on top of `background`.

Then you can draw on specific layers with:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{<layer_name>}
    <stuff>
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

So your code becomes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{set/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,align=center}}
        \node[set,fill=blue!20,text width=3cm](P) at (0, -1) {P Problems};
        \node[set,fill=green!20,text width=3cm](NP) at (3,+1) {NP Complete};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[fill=purple!20, fit=(P)(NP),draw,rounded corners=0.5cm,inner sep=1cm,label={NP Problems}]{};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

As requested by Lord @marmot. It took a while to get the colors right :)

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{wikigreen}{HTML}{B3DDD5}
\definecolor{wikiblue}{HTML}{D5D6FA}
\definecolor{wikipink}{HTML}{DBBAD2}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \tikzset{set/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=1.5cm,inner sep=0pt,align=center}}
        \node[thick,set,fill=wikigreen,text width=3cm](P) at (0, -1) {P Problems};
        \node[thick,set,fill=wikipink ,text width=3cm](NP) at (3,+1) {NP Complete};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[ultra thick,fill=wikiblue, fit=(P)(NP),draw,rounded corners=0.5cm,inner sep=1cm,label={NP Problems}]{};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! (+1) Perhaps load `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` to get ellipses and add `[font=\sf]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` to reproduce the Wikipedia figure even more closely.

Comment: @marmot Better?

Comment: Looks great! (And in order to honor the `\pi` day, you rotated the node orientation by `\pi`. That's really subtle ;-)

Comment: @marmot `\pi`es aren't problems U_U `\pi`neapple `\pi`zzas are!

Comment: Well, that's why I prefer `\pi`neapple `\pi`e (or was it cake?)

Comment: @marmot, `[font=\sffamily]`, `\sf` is obsolete in `latex` for + 20 years :-)

Comment: @marmot Look, I'll stop this here before CarLaTeX and Paulo Cereda, come to make an argument out of this :P

Comment: I guess they will agree but will mention that your figures are lacking [ducks](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/mwe/issues/3/sample-movie-files#comment-43891393)....

Comment: I prefer [Quero-Queros](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Southern_Lapwing.jpg) in my figures U_U

Answer (score 8):

`backgrounds` library does part of the job for you. It declares foreground, main and background layers. They can be used inside a scope with `on background layer` option:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds, shapes.geometric, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[ellipse, draw, fill=blue!30] (P) {P Problems};
        \node[ellipse, draw, fill=red!30, below right= 5mm and 5mm of P.east, anchor=north] (NP) {NP Complete};
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[fill=purple!20, fit={(P)(NP)([yshift=7mm]P.north)}, draw, rounded corners=0.5cm, label={[anchor=north, inner sep=3mm]\large{NP Problems}}, inner sep=3mm]{};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]