# Why fill work bad with nodes but okay with coordinates or anchors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

It seems to me that (path) fill command in tikz doesn't work quite well with (default) nodes. See the example below to understand what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [above]{Using nodes};
\draw (0,0) node(a){}--+(0:1) node(b){};
\draw (a)--++(-120:1) node(c){}--+(0:2) node(d){}--(b);
\fill (a) ..controls +(-2.5,-2) and +(-2,-3) ..(d)--(c)--(a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [above]{Using coordinates};
\tikzstyle every node=[coordinate]
\draw (0,0) node(a){}--+(0:1) node(b){};
\draw (a)--++(-120:1) node(c){}--+(0:2) node(d){}--(b);
\fill (a) ..controls +(-2.5,-2) and +(-2,-3) ..(d)--(c)--(a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [above]{Using anchors};
\draw (0,0) node(a){}--+(0:1) node(b){};
\draw (a)--++(-120:1) node(c){}--+(0:2) node(d){}--(b);
\fill (a.base) ..controls +(-2.5,-2) and +(-2,-3) ..(d.base)--(c.base)--(a.base);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**What is the reason for this weird behaviour of fill?**

Comment: There is nothing wrong. To fill a path in the way you expect, it needs to be closed. A node is not a point - it has size. You can use e.g. `a.center` to select the center point - and always close a path with `--cycle`.

Comment: Okay, then the real question is how to fill regions in a figure with nodes (shaped say circle). I guess the better way is to do the fill in background layer. If only two layers are needed, the method in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420113/157031 looks simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the problem with a non-closed path, only draw the fill like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [above]{Using nodes};
\path (0,0) node(a){}--+(0:1) node(b){};
\path (a)--++(-120:1) node(c){}--+(0:2) node(d){}--(b);
\draw[red, fill=yellow] (a) ..controls +(-2.5,-2) and +(-2,-3) ..(d)--(c)--(a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problematic fill]

To correct it; here is one way by using the center points of the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [above]{Using nodes};
\path (0,0) node(a){}--+(0:1) node(b){};
\path (a)--++(-120:1) node(c){}--+(0:2) node(d){}--(b);
\draw[red, fill=yellow] (a.center) ..controls +(-2.5,-2) and +(-2,-3) ..(d.center)--(c.center)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Better fill]

Comment: The 3rd example in the question shows that it works well with anchors. But I don't find it quite convincing that nodes affect the property of a path being closed.

Comment: okay, I am convinced that tikz is actually trying to close the path

Comment: It is not the nodes fault - you are the one who fill a path that are not closed. Nodes are not points. If you draw a path that are not closed, then TikZ is not trying to close it. TikZ is only doing, what you tell it.

Comment: I think you can add the relation of node and coordinate, coordinate is also a kind of node:  `\path coordinate` = `\path node[shape=coordinate]`, while node has a default shape `rectangle` and usually have the shape border.