# Draw a line flying across shapes and text content

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I want to draw a line between 2 nodes which may fly across existing shape and text content. In the example below, the line connecting `a` and `b` are intersecting with the label of `init` node. I can manually do a "line fly" after I notice the fact from tikz result. But is there some facility which can judge such circumstances and do automatical handling on the run? Something like `\draw [flyline, ->] (a) to (b)`

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, label={right:this is a test}] (init) {hello};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, above right=of init] (a) {a};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, below right=of init] (b) {b};
        \draw [->] (a) to (b);
        % I can change to use this after I find the intersect fact from the result
        %\draw (a) to (a|-init.north);
        %\draw [->] (b|-init.south) to (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Update:
Response to @Rmano's comment : Thansk for the reply. Yes, use layer can partly resolve my problem. I used `tikz-layers` package which provide 5 predefined layers. Code snippets is as the following:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, fit}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, label={[fill=white, inner sep=2pt, name=lbl]right:this is a test}] (init) {hello};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, above right=of init] (a) {a};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, below right=of init] (b) {b};
        \begin{scope}[on behind layer]
            \draw [->] (a) to (b);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node [fit=(init)(a)(b)(lbl), fill=cyan] () {};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result

[image]

One thing which I feel not quite perfect is that this makes the label covering background fill. Originally `label` is only text, now it get a shape which is not transparent to background fill. We can change the label fill the same as background fill `cyan`, but that create another dependency.

Is it possible that `label` can has a virtual boundary, which only masks underlining `draw` but not underlining `fill`?

---

Update : per @Rmano's suggestion to use `contour`, update the MWE to the following

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, fit}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}
\usepackage{bidicontour}
\usepackage{bidi}
\bidicontourlength{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, label={[inner sep=2pt, name=lbl]right:{\bidicontour{cyan}{this is a test}}}] (init) {hello};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, above right=of init] (a) {a};
        \node[rectangle, draw=black, below right=of init] (b) {b};
        \begin{scope}[on behind layer]
            \draw [->] (a) to (b);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node [fit=(init)(a)(b)(lbl), fill=cyan] () {};
        \end{scope}
        %\draw (a) to (a|-init.north);
        %\draw [->] (b|-init.south) to (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields nearly perfect result

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can draw the lines on a background layer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159139/what-is-required-to-use-background-layer-as-specified-in-tikz-manual and then use `fill=white, inner sep=1pt` for the text, for example.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for the reply. Layers basically works. I am editing the original post for some further question.

Comment: I would go the easy way, and `\colorlet{mybg}{cyan}` in the preamble and use `fill=mybg` --- so you have one point to change. Otherwise, give a look at [contour](https://ctan.org/pkg/contour). Notice that masking only draw will show the vertical line in the "belly" of the "a" char...

Comment: Exactly. `\node[rectangle, draw=black, label={[fill=cyan, inner sep=2pt, name=lbl]right:this is a test}] (init) {hello};`

Comment: @Rmano, `coutour` is wonderful. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that `label` can has a virtual boundary, which only masks underlining `draw` but not underlining `fill`?

I guess not.

Also in my opinion, there is not much difference between writing `label={[fill=cyan]text}` and `label={[...]\bidicontour{cyan}{text}}`. One always need to explicitly write the background color in `label={...}`.

The following example shows an attempt to write the background color only once. The definition of `pgfonlayerreversed` environment is copied from my [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562606/79060).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shapes, positioning, fit}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% copied from my previous answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562606
\let\pgfonlayerreversed\pgfonlayer
\let\endpgfonlayerreversed\endpgfonlayer

\xpatchcmd\pgfonlayerreversed
  {\expandafter\box\csname pgf@layerbox@#1\endcsname\begingroup}
  {\begingroup}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\endpgfonlayerreversed
  {\endgroup}
  {\endgroup\expandafter\box\csname pgf@layerbox@\pgfonlayer@name\endcsname}
  {}{\fail}

% similar to \tikz@background@framed, but using "pgfonlayerreversed" envi
\def\tikz@background@framed@reversed{%
  \tikz@background@save%
  \pgfonlayerreversed{background}
    \path[style=background rectangle] (\tikz@bg@minx,\tikz@bg@miny) rectangle (\tikz@bg@maxx,\tikz@bg@maxy);
  \endpgfonlayerreversed
}%

% similar to option "show background rectangle"
\tikzset{
  show background rectangle reversed/.style={
    execute at end picture=\tikz@background@framed@reversed
  }
}
\makeatother

% user interface
\tikzset{
  background color/.style={
    show background rectangle reversed,
    inner frame sep=2pt,
    background rectangle/.append style={draw=none, #1},
    every node/.append style={#1},
    every label/.append style={#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background color={fill=cyan}]
        \node[draw, label={[inner sep=2pt, name=lbl]right:this is a test}] (init) {hello};
        \node[draw, above right=of init] (a) {a};
        \node[draw, below right=of init] (b) {b};
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw [->] (a) to (b);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @muzimuzhi, Thank you for the answer. To my MWE question, it is the best answer which eliminate all the dependency. But for general case, it may lose some flexibility. For example, I need to have a more complicated background (not single color like [This](https://img.officetimeline.com/website/Content/website/addin-pro/swimlane-diagram-example-project-management.svg))

Comment: @EricSun I'm afraid in more complicated cases, using multiply layers is perhaps the only solution, similar to how `pgfplots` does, see the sec. 4.27 of its manual. Also, package [`pgfgantt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhi, `pgfgantt` is another treasure island for me, will do some further study.