# Tikz draw on layer stack from top to bottom (reversed order)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgflayers

In Tikz, I would like to have a command

```
\StartDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack
```

to draw all following elements on **bottom of the bottom layer** of the picture. That means following nodes and paths appear behind everything of the picture.
I need a command to return to standard behavior
`\StartDrawOnTopOfLayerStack`

At the moment I have to define as many layers as there are background nodes to be drawn.
I wonder if it can be realized easier?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background3}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background2}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background1}
\pgfsetlayers{background3,background2,background1,main}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%% block diagram
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (A) at (-4,0) {A};
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (B) at (-3,0) {B};
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (C) at (-2,0) {C};
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (D) at (-1,0) {D};

% \StartDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack

%% group 1
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background1}
\node[rectangle,fill=green,fit={(B) (C)}](G1) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

%% group 2
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background2}
\node[fill=blue,fit={(B) (C) (D)(G1)}](G2) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

%% group 3
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background3}
\node[fill=red,fit={(A)(B) (C) (D) (G1) (G2)}](G3) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Tikz layers really just change the order in which things are drawn.  If you create all the coordinates first and draw tthings in the right order, you don't need layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short introduction, from bottom to top:

1. Similar to environment `pgfonlayer`, new environment `pgfonlayerreversed` is defined. Its contents will be typeset on specified layer but in reversed order, i.e. latest contents are typeset *below* accumulated contents.
2. Similar to option `on background layer` in library `backgrounds`, new option `on background layer reversed` is defined which makes use of new environment `pgfonlayerreversed` (on layer `background`).
3. Finally, `\StartDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack` and `\EndDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack` constitute a special `scope` environment, in which every use of `\node` is equivalent to `\scoped[on lowest layer] \node`.

Full implementation:

```
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562577
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, fit}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% similar to env "pgfonlayer", but the latest contents are typeset on
% lowest bottom (on reversed order)

\let\pgfonlayerreversed\pgfonlayer
\let\endpgfonlayerreversed\endpgfonlayer

\xpatchcmd\pgfonlayerreversed
  {\expandafter\box\csname pgf@layerbox@#1\endcsname\begingroup}
  {\begingroup}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\endpgfonlayerreversed
  {\endgroup}
  {\endgroup\expandafter\box\csname pgf@layerbox@\pgfonlayer@name\endcsname}
  {}{\fail}


\tikzset{
  on background layer reversed/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayerreversed{background}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty
      \tikzset{every on background layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayerreversed}
  }
}


\def\StartDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack{%
  \scope\relax
  % patch \path variants to auto insert "\scoped[on lowest layer]"
  % currently \node, \pic, \coordinate, and \matrix are patched
  \let\tikz@path@overlay\tikz@path@overlay@autoscoped
  \let\tikz@path@overlayed\tikz@path@overlayed@autoscoped
}

\def\EndDrawOnTopOfLayerStack{%
  \endscope
}

\def\tikz@path@overlay@autoscoped#1{%
  \let\tikz@signal@path=\tikz@signal@path% for detection at begin of matrix cell
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar<%
    {\tikz@path@overlayed{#1}}
    {\scoped[on background layer reversed] \path #1}}%
\def\tikz@path@overlayed@autoscoped#1<#2>{%
  \scoped[on background layer reversed] \path<#2> #1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % text nodes
  \node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (A) at (-4,0) {A};
  \node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (B) at (-3,0) {B};
  \node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (C) at (-2,0) {C};
  \node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow] (D) at (-1,0) {D};

  % background rectangles
  \StartDrawOnBottomOfLayerStack
    \node[rectangle,fill=green,fit={(B) (C)}](G1) {};
    \node[fill=blue,fit={(B) (C) (D)(G1)}](G2) {};
    \node[fill=red,fit={(A)(B) (C) (D) (G1) (G2)}](G3) {};
  \EndDrawOnTopOfLayerStack
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely impressive answer, which corresponds exactly to my imagination. I have great respect.  I hope this answer helps many more users and will soon lead to a similar native Tikz implementation.

Comment: @Tobias I improved the implementation of `pgfonlayerreversed` env.